# how do I display json results using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

here is my ajax request :

```
 $(".colorme").on("click", function () {
        var c = $(this);
        var b = "id=" + c.attr("id");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "../../colorme",
        data: b,
        success: function (a) {
                   $.when(c.fadeOut(300).promise()).done(function () {

            if (c.hasClass("btn")) {

                c.removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-success").text(a).fadeIn()

            } else {
                c.replaceWith('<span class="notice_mid_link">' + a + "</span>")

            }
        })
        }});
        return false
    })
```

so here is what I receive as a response :

```
{"f0d8c0":0.3269616519174,"d8d8d8":0.22377581120944,"181818":0.10926253687316,"d8a890":0.091268436578171,"303030":0.054454277286136}
```

I would like to be able display each one of those values as a pair.Right now it returns :`[object OBJECT]`

Comment: have you tried jQuery.parseJSON() ? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use,

```
data = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({type: "POST", url: "../../colorme", data: b, success: function (a) {

  resp = jQuery.parseJSON(a);
  alert(resp.f0d8c0);
  alert(resp.d8d8d8); //maybe you need to use a better way to name the data?

               $.when(c.fadeOut(300).promise()).done(function () {

        if (c.hasClass("btn")) {

            c.removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-success").text(a).fadeIn()

        } else {
            c.replaceWith('<span class="notice_mid_link">' + a + "</span>")

        }
    })
    }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(a);
alert( obj.f0d8c0);
alert( obj.d8d8d8);
```

You can assign your response value in `var a =$.parseJSON(RESPONSE VALUE)`

For more Details Read this [LINK](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)